# Open Source DBMS

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, jsp, database

I have to create two web applications using:

- ASP.NET
- JSP

Without using MySQL, I'm looking for a free (open source) DBMS.

I found Firebird and and Postgresql, but I'm not sure about them; Is there any other powerful DBMS you've already used in this case ?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with MySQL or Postgres? They're the most used; are there any specific problems you're having with them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used both Firebird and Postgres, and they're fine. You could also look at [SQLite3](http://www.sqlite.org/), or one of the "NoSQL" data stores, like [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/), [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/), or [Riak](https://wiki.basho.com/display/RIAK/Riak).

Firebird and SQLite have the distinction of being embeddable databases, meaning you can easily ship them as a part of your application without having to require the end user to set up the database separately.